# How to prevent duplicate product action in Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase, enhanced-ecommerce

I have implemented the Enhanced Ecommerce in my android app. First the user views a product list(impression), then product detail(action_detail),add to cart(add to cart). Now if user deleted the cart and then adds the same product to cart again, then addtocart action will have multiple duplicate hits. Is there any way to protect or prevent such duplicate action hits from the same user or during the same session rather

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with mobile tracking, but for the web version you'd implement to a "remove from cart" call (actually a "addProduct" with type of "remove") when one (or all, as in a cart deletion) products are removed from the cart. I'm fairly certain that exists for mobile, too.

Comment: do you mean that the total number of "add to cart" events for that product after this cycle is 3?